# Chrome Extension. Onload Blur fails.

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blur

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that blurs any textarea of a page when loading, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Here's the code:

Manifest.json:

```
{
"name":"foo",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version":2,
"description":"foo",
"content_scripts":[{
     "matches":["http://*/*"],
     "js":["content.js", "jquery-1.8.3.min.js"]}]
 }
```

Content.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").blur})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").blur();
```

[blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) is a method.

Comment: @EdHeal would you really call them pop though?

Comment: Could not be bothered to type in alternative rock (btw that was a cut and paste job). Parklife is good. Has hidden Connotations.